# Where can I find lore about the Singing-Luminous Eye of the Speakers?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, lore, artifacts

I was reading through [Narriseminek's wiki page](https://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Narriseminek) when I saw this:

> The name of Narriseminek's domain is sung and incomprehensible to non-proteans, but is commonly called the Drifting Mountain of Narriseminek the Crownless. It is located within the Borderlands between the Maelstrom and Nirvana, and contains a great temple to the Speakers of the Depths, and **the mysterious artifact known as the Singing-Luminous Eye of the Speakers**.

I've checked the wiki, Archives of Nethys, d2opfsrd, but nothing I can find even mentions it.
So is there anything I've missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### It seems to be mysterious

Unfortunately, the current answer seems to be that *there is nowhere* to find lore about the Singing-Luminous Eye of the Speakers. The Artifact in question is referenced in [Campaign Setting Concordance of Rivals](https://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Concordance_of_Rivals_(sourcebook)) and *that's it*. The section offers no more information about it than what can be found on the Wiki page you linked.

The other sources on the wiki (AP#22 End of Eternity and Pathfinder Chronicles: The Great Beyond) offer no additional details, and I cannot find any other reference to it elsewhere, including the sources on the Speakers of the Depths wiki page (only adding Planar Adventures).